# Group by column value and within 3 days of each other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a quite complicated problem and could not find an answer I could apply. In a dataframe with Work, Tasks and Date (String, String, Date), I would like to group according to work but the only when dates are within 3 days of each other:

| Work | Task | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Work 1 | Task 1 | 08-12-2021 |
| Work 1 | Task 2 | 09-12-2021 |
| Work 1 | Task 3 | 10-12-2021 |
| Work 2 | Task 1 | 20-12-2021 |
| Work 2 | Task 2 | 20-12-2021 |
| Work 2 | Task 3 | 21-12-2021 |
| Work 1 | Task 1 | 10-12-2021 |
| Work 1 | Task 2 | 11-12-2021 |

Dataset:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([['Work1','Task1','08-12-2021'], ['Work1','Task2','09-12-2021'], ['Work1','Task3','10-12-2021'],['Work2','Task1','20-12-2021'],['Work2','Task2','20-12-2021'],['Work2','Task3','21-12-2021'],['Work1','Task1','10-12-2022'],['Work1','Task2','11-12-2022']], columns=['Work', 'Task','Date'])
```

What I tried: I calculated a dataframe with Grouped Work, Start Date of Work (agg. min date), Finish Date of Work (agg. max date), First Task, Latest Task.

```
df2 = df.groupby(by=('Work')).agg(Max=('Date','max'), Min=('Date','min')).reset_index()

df2["Finish_Date"] = df2.merge(df, left_on=["Work", "Max"], right_on=["Work", "Date"])['Task']
df2["Start_Date"] = df2.merge(df, left_on=["Work", "Min"], right_on=["Work", "Date"])['Task']
```

What I get:

| Work | Start Date | Finish Date | First Task | Last Task |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Work 1 | 08-12-2021 | 11-12-2022 | Task 1 | Task 2 |
| Work 2 | 20-12-2021 | 21-12-2021 | Task 1 | Task 3 |

The problem is that the work cannot last more than 3 days and I would like to group according to work but within 3 days of each. I tried very unsuccessfully to create a new column with work + start date to distinguish between different works. What I want:

| Work | Start Date | Finish Date | First Task | Last Task |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Work 1 - 08-12-2021 | 08-12-2021 | 10-12-2022 | Task 1 | Task 3 |
| Work 2 - 20-12-2021 | 20-12-2021 | 21-12-2021 | Task 1 | Task 3 |
| Work 1 - 10-12-2022 | 10-12-2022 | 11-12-2022 | Task 1 | Task 2 |

Thank you

Comment: Why is the `Last Task` `task_3` instead of `task_2` since this is the last task on `11-12-2021`?

Comment: Thank you Nuri, corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do something like this:

```
# Assuming the data is sorted by date:
# First, convent the date to a datetime.
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%d-%m-%Y")

# then find the gaps of 3 or more days and label the consecutive runs
groupings = (df['Date'].diff().dt.days >= 3).cumsum()

# we can now group by these labels and find the min/max
final = df.groupby(groupings).agg({'Date': ['min','max'], 'Task': ['first','last']})

# Then, to flatten the multiindex, we can use:
final.columns = ['Start Date', 'End Date', 'First Task', 'Last Task']

===================== 
Result:
     Start Date   End Date First Task Last Task
Date
0    2021-12-08 2021-12-10      Task1     Task3
1    2021-12-20 2021-12-21      Task1     Task3
2    2022-12-10 2022-12-11      Task1     Task2
```

Hope that helps!

EDIT for clarification:

If different Work items are close in date but need to stay in separate groups, you can use `groupby(['Work',groupings])` instead.

In addition, if you have something like the following:

| Work | Date |
| --- | --- |
| T1 | 2022-01-03 |
| T2 | 2022-01-05 |
| T2 | 2022-01-07 |
| T1 | 2022-01-09 |

you may want to use `groupings = (df.groupby('Work').Date.diff().dt.days >= 3).cumsum()` so that the two `T1`s appear in different groups.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Should I add in final df.groupby(by=['Work',groupings] in order to have the result grouped by Work as well?

Comment: Yes, I forgot that part. That will solve some of the problem of having overlapping groups. You may also want to groupby Work before calculating consecutive dates: `grouping = (df.groupby('Work').Date.diff().dt.days >=3).cumsum()` so that e.g. [W1,W2,W2,W2,W1] on consecutive days has the two W1s in different groups.

Comment: I've edited my answer to help clarify this.

Comment: Works quite good with 100K rows, thank you. However could never completed with 10M+ rows, need to find a faster way :/

Comment: My guess is it would be the groupby that is slow. There are many other posts on StackOverflow to that effect, especially when grouping on strings. If there aren't too many kinds of Work, you could try making it a categorical. Otherwise, you might want to partition your data into pieces that are quicker to process.

Comment: Solved it with groupby and pd.Grouper freq='3d'. 1.5 min calculation

Comment: You should double check that pd.Grouper(freq='3d') is actually performing the behavior that you want: it doesn't just group events that are close to each other, it partitions the calendar into blocks and groups only those that fall into the same block.